# What is the meaning of なんで here and why?

Tags: meaning

I've been told that the translation of the following sentence:

１００年以上続く古い会社なんで不便もたまにあります

is: This company has been established for more than 100 years, so it is sometimes inconvenient with many things.

I understand both parts of the sentence, but I don't get the connection なんで. Not even in the dictionary says that なんで's meaning is "so". The only meaning of なんで I know is "why?" but here it makes no sense.

Thank you

Comment: It's a variant of なので。 I'm sure you're familiar with ので？

Comment: oookay! I didn't know that. I am familiar with ので (similar to から). Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sentence, なんで is a contraction of なので. Not the same thing as the usual なんで which is used in questions like なんで食べない？.

なので means **so** (expressing consequence).

```
cause なので consequence
cause なんで consequence
```

`なんで` is more casual, but not as casual as だから.